# FFT of A Musical Note

Tags: python, fft, wav

I've been getting really confused with FFT in python. What I'm trying to do is plot the FFT of the note number 61 (or middle C#). Here is the code that I tried to use which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377665/python-scipy-fft-wav-files) using [this](https://files.fm/u/j4ybb4rr) wav file. After running that code, I got this output after zooming in a bit.

[image: output]

I think that this is completely wrong due to the fact that after looking online, the note number 61 has a frequency of 277.2hz. This means that there should be a peak around that value right? But to me, it seems like that the values are completely off. This is the code that I'm running right now to get the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.io import wavfile # get the api
fs, data = wavfile.read("MAPS_ISOL_NO_P_S0_M61_AkPnBsdf.wav") # load the data
a = data.T[0] # this is a two channel soundtrack, I get the first track
b=[(ele/2**8.)*2-1 for ele in a] # this is 8-bit track, b is now normalized on [-1,1)
c = fft(b) # create a list of complex number
d = len(c)/2  # you only need half of the fft list
plt.plot(abs(c[:(d-1)]),'r') 
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.show()
```

I'm also not sure if I have the axis labeled correctly for the x and y axis as I believe each entry in the array is a bin of size Fs / N where Fs is the sample rate and N is the size of the FFT? I'm just really confused and overwhelmed after looking online for weeks about all this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using numpy or scipy fft? You should show your imports too.

Comment: Your X axis looks like bin indices rather than frequencies to me ?

Comment: Indeed as @PaulR mentions, in your line `plt.plot(abs(c[:(d-1)]),'r') ` you provide just one array, meaning that the X axis will be assumed to be the index and not frequency.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056) for an explanation of the relationship between FFT bin index and frequency.

Comment: Right I mentioned I wasn't sure if it was bins or frequencies so that confirmed it for me. How would I go about converting the bin indicies to frequencies? I also added the packages I imported.