# I need to FFT wav files?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy

I saw [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377665/python-scipy-fft-wav-files) about using fft on wav files and tried to implement it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile # get the api
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from pylab import *
import sys

def f(filename):
    fs, data = wavfile.read(filename) # load the data
    a = data.T[0] # this is a two channel soundtrack, I get the first track
    b=[(ele/2**8.)*2-1 for ele in a] # this is 8-bit track, b is now normalized on [-1,1)
    c = fft(b) # create a list of complex number
    d = len(c)/2  # you only need half of the fft list
    plt.plot(abs(c[:(d-1)]),'r')
    savefig(filename+'.png',bbox_inches='tight')

files = sys.argv[1:]
for ele in files:
    f(ele)
quit()
```

But whenever I call it:

```
$ python fft.py 0.0/4515-11057-0058.flac.wav-16000.wav
```

I get the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "fft.py", line 18, in <module>
>     f(ele)
>    File "fft.py", line 10, in f
>     b=[(ele/2**8.)*2-1 for ele in a] # this is 8-bit track, b is now normalized on [-1,1)
> TypeError: 'numpy.int16' object is not iterable
> ```

How can I create a script that generates frequency distributions for each file in the list of arguments?

Comment: It seems that ``a `` is only an integer. Are you sure that your track is two channel?

Comment: @alexblae they are all single channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message states that you are trying to iterate over an integer (`a`). When you define `a` via

```
a = data.T[0]
```

you grab the first value of `data.T`. Since your data files are single channel, you are taking the first value of the first channel (an integer). Changing this to

```
a = data.T
```

will fix your problem.