# Trying to get the frequencies of a .wav file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, wav

What I'm trying to do seems simple: I want to know exactly what frequencies there are in a .wav file at given times; i.e. "from the time *n* milliseconds to *n + 10* milliseconds, the average frequency of the sound was *x* hertz". I have seen people talking about Fourier transforms and Goertzel algorithms, as well as various modules, that I can't seem to figure out how to get to do what I've described.

What I'm looking for is a solution like this pseudocode, or at least one that will do something like what the pseudocode is getting at:

```
import some_module_that_can_help_me_do_this as freq

file = 'output.wav'
start_time = 1000  # Start 1000 milliseconds into the file
end_time = 1010  # End 10 milliseconds thereafter

print("Average frequency = " + str(freq.average(start_time, end_time)) + " hz")
```

I don't come from a mathematics background, so I don't want to have to understand the implementation details.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377665/python-scipy-fft-wav-files/23378284

Comment: Related: https://pythondsp.rob-elder.com/loading-wav-files-and-showing-frequency-response/

Comment: Do you mean dominant frequency? Mind any real audio signal contains mix of various frequencies. You can simply compute average (e.g. from link that @Primusa shared), but I doubt it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'm looking for. For my `output.wav` file I'm using a recording of myself playing on a Casio, so there'd be noise in the recording. Is that what I'd want the dominant frequency for?

Comment: Correct. Did my code work for you?

Comment: Yeees, but see my comment below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you'd like to detect [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm) of a sound (and it seems you do), then in terms of Python libraries your best bet is [aubio](https://pypi.org/project/aubio/). Please consult this [example](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/python/demos/demo_pitch.py) for implementation.

```
import sys
from aubio import source, pitch

win_s = 4096
hop_s = 512 

s = source(your_file, samplerate, hop_s)
samplerate = s.samplerate

tolerance = 0.8

pitch_o = pitch("yin", win_s, hop_s, samplerate)
pitch_o.set_unit("midi")
pitch_o.set_tolerance(tolerance)

pitches = []
confidences = []

total_frames = 0
while True:
    samples, read = s()
    pitch = pitch_o(samples)[0]
    pitches += [pitch]
    confidence = pitch_o.get_confidence()
    confidences += [confidence]
    total_frames += read
    if read < hop_s: break

print("Average frequency = " + str(np.array(pitches).mean()) + " hz")
```

Be sure to check [docs](https://aubio.org/manpages/latest/aubiopitch.1.html) on pitch detection methods.

I also thought you might be interested in estimation of mean frequency and some other audio parameters without using any special libraries. Let's just use numpy! This should give you much better insight into how such audio features can be calculated. It's based off [specprop](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seewave/versions/2.1.0/topics/specprop) from [seewave](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seewave/versions/2.1.0) package. Check docs for meaning of computed features.

```
import numpy as np

def spectral_properties(y: np.ndarray, fs: int) -> dict:
    spec = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y))
    freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(y), d=1 / fs)
    spec = np.abs(spec)
    amp = spec / spec.sum()
    mean = (freq * amp).sum()
    sd = np.sqrt(np.sum(amp * ((freq - mean) ** 2)))
    amp_cumsum = np.cumsum(amp)
    median = freq[len(amp_cumsum[amp_cumsum <= 0.5]) + 1]
    mode = freq[amp.argmax()]
    Q25 = freq[len(amp_cumsum[amp_cumsum <= 0.25]) + 1]
    Q75 = freq[len(amp_cumsum[amp_cumsum <= 0.75]) + 1]
    IQR = Q75 - Q25
    z = amp - amp.mean()
    w = amp.std()
    skew = ((z ** 3).sum() / (len(spec) - 1)) / w ** 3
    kurt = ((z ** 4).sum() / (len(spec) - 1)) / w ** 4

    result_d = {
        'mean': mean,
        'sd': sd,
        'median': median,
        'mode': mode,
        'Q25': Q25,
        'Q75': Q75,
        'IQR': IQR,
        'skew': skew,
        'kurt': kurt
    }

    return result_d
```

Comment: Worked really well, but I had to tweak a few things. It first gave me an error saying `confidence` was not defined, and I wasn't sure how to calculate it, so I just hardcoded it to 0.8. Then it gave me a concatenation type error because `np.array(pitches).mean()` doesn't return a string, so I `str()`ed it and now it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @kitty4537 for the effort to point out problems. Fixed. As an extras I have thrown in code that takes you through calculation of various spectral features. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

This answer is quite late, but you could try this:

*(Note: I deserve very little credit for this since I got most of it from other SO posts and this great article on FFT using Python: https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/)*

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import *
from scipy.io import wavfile


def freq(file, start_time, end_time):

    # Open the file and convert to mono
    sr, data = wavfile.read(file)
    if data.ndim > 1:
        data = data[:, 0]
    else:
        pass

    # Return a slice of the data from start_time to end_time
    dataToRead = data[int(start_time * sr / 1000) : int(end_time * sr / 1000) + 1]

    # Fourier Transform
    N = len(dataToRead)
    yf = rfft(dataToRead)
    xf = rfftfreq(N, 1 / sr)

    # Uncomment these to see the frequency spectrum as a plot
    # plt.plot(xf, np.abs(yf))
    # plt.show()

    # Get the most dominant frequency and return it
    idx = np.argmax(np.abs(yf))
    freq = xf[idx]
    return freq
```

This code can work for any `.wav` file, but it may be slightly off since it only returns the most dominant frequency, and also because it only uses the first channel of the audio (if not mono).

If you want to learn more about how the Fourier transform works, check out this video by 3blue1brown with a visual explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Comment: Hey! This is super helpful. What if I have multiple frequencies in the file and I'm not super sure where they start and end? Also, what do I do for DTMF tones? I feed in a DTMF 1 tone into this program and I get 1209 Hz in return, but I also need the 697 Hz too. Please help as I am at a loss of where to go from here.

Comment: I actually ran into a similar issue with timing. I'm unfortunately not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I felt the OPs frustration - it shouldnt be so hard to find how to get values of the sprectrogram instead of seeing the spectrogram image if someone needs to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import librosa
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

filename = 'filename.wav'
Fs = 44100
clip, sample_rate = librosa.load(filename, sr=Fs)

n_fft = 1024  # frame length 
start = 0 

hop_length=512

#commented out code to display Spectrogram
X = librosa.stft(clip, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length)
#Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
#plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
#librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=Fs, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz') 
#If to pring log of frequencies  
#librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=Fs, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
#plt.colorbar()

#librosa.display.waveplot(clip, sr=Fs)
#plt.show()

#now print all values 

t_samples = np.arange(clip.shape[0]) / Fs
t_frames = np.arange(X.shape[1]) * hop_length / Fs
#f_hertz = np.arange(N / 2 + 1) * Fs / N       # Works only when N is even
f_hertz = np.fft.rfftfreq(n_fft, 1 / Fs)         # Works also when N is odd

#example
print('Time (seconds) of last sample:', t_samples[-1])
print('Time (seconds) of last frame: ', t_frames[-1])
print('Frequency (Hz) of last bin:   ', f_hertz[-1])

print('Time (seconds) :', len(t_samples))

#prints array of time frames 
print('Time of frames (seconds) : ', t_frames)
#prints array of frequency bins
print('Frequency (Hz) : ', f_hertz)

print('Number of frames : ', len(t_frames))
print('Number of bins : ', len(f_hertz))

#This code is working to printout frame by frame intensity of each frequency
#on top line gives freq bins
curLine = 'Bins,'
for b in range(1, len(f_hertz)):
    curLine += str(f_hertz[b]) + ','
print(curLine)

curLine = ''
for f in range(1, len(t_frames)):
    curLine = str(t_frames[f]) + ','
    for b in range(1, len(f_hertz)): #for each frame, we get list of bin values printed
        curLine += str("%.02f" % np.abs(X[b, f])) + ','
        #remove format of the float for full details if needed
        #curLine += str(np.abs(X[b, f])) + ','
        #print other useful info like phase of frequency bin b at frame f.
        #curLine += str("%.02f" % np.angle(X[b, f])) + ',' 
    print(curLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the below, it worked for me with a sine wave file with a freq of 1234 I generated 
[from this page.](http://[https://www.audiocheck.net/audiofrequencysignalgenerator_sinetone.php][1])

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

def freq(file, start_time, end_time):
    sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(file)
    start_point = int(sample_rate * start_time / 1000)
    end_point = int(sample_rate * end_time / 1000)
    length = (end_time - start_time) / 1000
    counter = 0
    for i in range(start_point, end_point):
        if data[i] < 0 and data[i+1] > 0:
            counter += 1
    return counter/length    

freq("sin.wav", 1000 ,2100)
1231.8181818181818
```

edited: cleaned up for loop a bit

Comment: Thanks, but there appears to be a problem. When I run the code as you have it here (with the appropriate print statement for the `freq` call), it gives me the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. So I tried changing line 10 to `if data[i].all() < 0 and data[i+1].all() > 0:` and then `if data[i].any() < 0 and data[i+1].any() > 0:` , but both times I just got `0.0` no matter what times I specified for start/end.

Comment: That's odd, can you share the file and the start/end time you're passing to this function?

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: Running Python 3.7. Here's the version that raises a `ValueError`: `https://pastebin.com/aT4F4bg4` And here's one version that returns `0.0` no matter what start/end times I use: `https://pastebin.com/CB9TwbLT` Here's one that also only returns `0.0`: `https://pastebin.com/rCSw5Rc4`

Comment: The first one is essentially exactly what you've written, the other two are me trying to fix the `ValueError` by doing what the error message told me to do (i.e., put `.any()` and `.all()` onto the data arrays)

Comment: @kitty4537 Something is off about that data array. It probably has nested arrays for some reason. Look into the structure of the array. It should contain just the values of the sound sampling taken at the sample rate.

Comment: This algorithm can work only in case of a single frequency present in the signal. Essentially it's a simplified way of calculating zero crossings rate.

Comment: How should one go about it if you have DTMF tones? @LukaszTracewski

Comment: @developer01 It's not my answer, but I don't think the `freq` function would work beyond the simplest case.