# How to find the frequency of an audio?

Tags: audio, frequency

So to put it simply, I want to find the frequencies of an audio file.
There's only 2 frequencies in it (one in the left ear, one in the right ear) as it's a binaural. What I want to find is these two frequencies. I have audacity and audition.

Comment: Read about the (fast) Fourier transform. In short, it transforms your signal from time domain to frequency domain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get the frequencies of a .wav file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612204/trying-to-get-the-frequencies-of-a-wav-file-in-python)