# Spectroscopic data analysos using ML

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have RF spectra of various samples consisting of 5 components in the frequency range of 10MHz to 1000MHz, 1000-2000MHz and so on. I need to predict one of the component in an unknown sample. can anybody please help me on how to represent the data and which ML algorithms to be used?

Comment: So one column is the target or you need to predict values from all columns? Also could you explain what do you mean by 'unknown sample'.

Comment: one column is the target. Unknown sample means a spectra where the concentrations of the components in the sample are not known. the concentration of the required component will be predicted using the model created.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [sklearn imputer module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute). It sounds like you have what is know as missing values. There is a couple of ways of imputing those values.

From the simplest way (imput always some value). To imputing based on the [mean or median](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer) of the column. Or using something more fancy like the [Iterative Imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer).

At the end you just want to fill the gaps to be able to use some of the ml models. There are some models (like the trees and forest I believe) that can handle missing values but they don't perfom as good as using imputation.

Let me know if this was helpful or I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to find pitch of the unlabeled audio sequence. I'm attaching a link of another question, please view it.
link: [Trying to get the frequencies of a .wav file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612204/trying-to-get-the-frequencies-of-a-wav-file-in-python)