# (Python 3.8) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: typeerror, python-3.8

i tried to use this code here:
[Python Scipy FFT wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377665/python-scipy-fft-wav-files)

and got the following error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Any solution for that?

Comment: Please provide the exact code you wrote, right now your question is about nothing

Comment: what is the name of .py?

Comment: i named it simply "test1.py"

Comment: Any ideas? In my opinion i do not call any 'module' object....